# How to display all record from database in Drupal?

Tags: database

```
global $user;
$nid = '650';


$query = db_select('field_data_field_batch_reference');
$query->fields('field_data_field_batch_reference', array('field_batch_reference_target_id'));
$query->condition('entity_id', $nid, '=');
$result = $query->execute()->fetchField();
drupal_set_message($result);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different method on the query object to get all results.

e.g `fetchCol()` to get an array when querying for a single column value (in this case `field_batch_reference_target_id`):

```
global $user; 
$nid = '650';

$query = db_select('field_data_field_batch_reference');
$query->fields('field_data_field_batch_reference', array('field_batch_reference_target_id'));
$query->condition('entity_id', $nid, '=');
$target_ids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . var_export($target_ids, 1) . '</pre>);
```

You could also then load those entities with something like

```
$entities = entity_load_multiple('entity_type', $target_ids);
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . var_export($entities, 1) . '</pre>);
```

Keep in mind that will load all results, so you may want to add a limit to your query instead, e.g:

```
$query->range(0, 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch all the records from the database, you can also use fetchAll() with your query.

```
$query = db_select('field_data_field_batch_reference',fr);
$query->fields('fr', array('field_batch_reference_target_id'));
$query->condition('entity_id', $nid, '=');
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

It will return multiple results to display.

Hope it works for you!